# List vs Arrays in a generated proxy class in c#

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service and when I generated the client proxy class with svcutil it changed my list properties to arrays. is there an option to ensure that I maintain the Lists without modifying the generated class in C#?

```
//The object in the service…

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "3.0.4506.2152")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://brax.com/data/Query")]
public partial class PayloadType
{
    private List<PersonType> personBasedQueryField;
    private List<LocationType> locationBasedQueryField;


//Generated class...

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "3.0.4506.2152")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://brax.com/data/Query")]
public partial class PayloadType
{
    private PersonType[] personBasedQueryField;
    private LocationType[] locationBasedQueryField;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are options in the Service Reference in Visual Studio.  You can choose to have collections generated as List there.

**UPDATE:** If you're using [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx?ppud=4), you can use this option:

```
/collectionType:<type>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create the client proxy by adding a service reference from within the Visual Studio, then you can later edit that configuration. In that edit dialog, you can specify whether you want to have arrays, lists, ObservableCollections (and I think there were some more options).

[image]

With the svcutil I don't know if it is possible to change that option.

Comment: When using svcutil.exe, you can use the /collectionType:<type> option.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on ServiceReference, choose Configure Service Reference. And change Collection type to System.Collections.Generic.List.