# How to make request body for generic list as request parameter in wcf service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

> [DataContract]
>
> public class OrderDetails
> {
> [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
> public string OrderReference { get; set; }
>
> ```
>     [DataMember]
>     public List<Product> Product { get; set; }
> }
> ```
>
> [MessageContract]
> public class Product
> {
> [MessageBodyMember]
> public string Number { get; set; }
> [MessageBodyMember]
> public string Code { get; set; }
> [MessageBodyMember]
> public string Quantity { get; set; }
>
> ```
> }
> ```
>
> urn:OrderDetails
>
> urn:OrderReference?</urn:OrderReference>
>
> urn:Product
>
> urn:Product
>
> urn:Number?</urn:LineNumber>
>
> urn:Code?</urn:ProductCode>
>
> urn:Quantity?</urn:Quantity>
> </urn:Product>
> </urn:Product> </urn:OrderDetails>
>
> But I want below output urn:OrderDetails
> urn:OrderReferencedf</urn:OrderReference>
>
> urn:Product
> urn:Numberf</urn:LineNumber>
> urn:Codedf</urn:ProductCode>
> </urn:Product>
> urn:Product
> urn:Numberf</urn:LineNumber>
> urn:Codedf</urn:ProductCode>
> </urn:Product> </urn:OrderDetails> so what I change in SerivceContract?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, here are some suggestions: 1. Visual Studio has a service reference capability that allows you to reference one project to another. 2. For an explanation of the use of parameters, see the link below:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641692/can-we-send-a-generic-list-listcustomobject-as-a-parameter-to-a-wcf-operati](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641692/can-we-send-a-generic-list-listcustomobject-as-a-parameter-to-a-wcf-operati) Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Jiayao thanks for the quick reaply,